# ibatis: improve insert performance

Tags: java, sql, insert, ibatis, batch-processing

I am using ibatis for my sql insert stmt. In my code I am parsing files line by line from a folder. Each line that matches criteria, need to be inserted into database.
Total number of insert in a single run of program can be any where along 200k.

```
    SqlSession sess = null;    
    this.sess = sf.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH, false);
    for (each file) {
     for( each line matching criteria ){
         this.sess.insert("com.logs.util.insertFileInfo", fileData);
         insertcount++;
         if(insert count == 10)
              this.sess.commit();
         }    
      }
      if(insert count > 0){
           this.sess.commit();
      }   
    }
```

This style slowly takes up lot of memory and after some times throws OutOfMemory exception.
How can I improve performance here?

Answer (score 0):

Is it your intention to commit after every 10 inserts? It looks like you only do so after the first 10 inserts. I guess that you would need something like

```
if ((insertCount % 10) == 0) {
   this.sess.commit();
}
```

Those uncommitted changes have to be stored somewhere. I'm not familiar with Ibatis but if the uncommitted changes are being stored in a buffer allocated by Ibatis then you will eventually run out of memory if you don't commit the changes.

Comment: With that change, you will commit after the first 10 lines and then after each file whether a commit is required or not; it doesn't really sound right. If a file contains (say) 50K lines then those 50K items will have to be buffered somewhere. They will either be retained by Ibatis, the underlying JDBC driver or the DBMS. If you use the mod operator (%) then you will never buffer more than 10 pending changes. Also, don't forget to commit the session after the outer loop completes.